# Are links deprecated in Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

According to the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/), links are described as "legacy". In particular, there's this warning:

> Warning: The --link flag is a deprecated legacy feature of Docker. It may eventually be removed. Unless you absolutely need to continue using it, we recommend that you use user-defined networks to facilitate communication between two containers instead of using --link. One feature that user-defined networks do not support that you can do with --link is sharing environmental variables between containers. However, you can use other mechanisms such as volumes to share environment variables between containers in a more controlled way.

Contrariwise, Docker Compose also has a "links" feature, which is *not* deprecated according to the [Docker Compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/links).

Is there any relationship between the Docker "Legacy container links" feature and Docker Compose's "links" section? If so, why are they deprecated in one and not in the other? If not, why are they both called "links"?

([I originally asked this questions in the Docker forums](https://forums.docker.com/t/are-links-deprecated-in-docker-compose/27348), but got no reply).

Answer (score 1):

I found this question because today it looked almost like "links:" stopped supporting container name mapping since Docker 25.x

However the reason was that I was still using `docker-compose`, which according to this page, is unsupported: https://docs.docker.com/compose/migrate/

> The final Compose V1 release, version 1.29.2, was May 10, 2021. These packages haven't received any security updates since then. Use at your own risk.

When I switched to `docker compose` as the page recommends, the "links:" container name mapping works as usual:

```yml
services:
  container1:
    image: pingidentity/pingtoolkit
    links:
    - container2:db
    command: ping db

  container2:
    image: pingidentity/pingtoolkit
    command: sleep infinity
```

proof:

```bash
$ docker compose up
[+] Running 2/0
 ✔ Container repro-container2-1  Created                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 ✔ Container repro-container1-1  Created                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
Attaching to container1-1, container2-1
container2-1  | ----- Starting hook: ./bootstrap.sh
container2-1  | ### Bootstrap
container2-1  | ### Using the default container user and group
container2-1  | ### Container user and group
container2-1  | ###     user : ping (id: 9031)
container2-1  | ###     group: root (id: 0)
container2-1  | ----- Starting hook: /opt/entrypoint.sh
container2-1  | Running command: sleep infinity
container1-1  | ----- Starting hook: ./bootstrap.sh
container1-1  | ### Bootstrap
container1-1  | ### Using the default container user and group
container1-1  | ### Container user and group
container1-1  | ###     user : ping (id: 9031)
container1-1  | ###     group: root (id: 0)
container1-1  | ----- Starting hook: /opt/entrypoint.sh
container1-1  | Running command: ping db
container1-1  | PING db (10.50.3.2): 56 data bytes
container1-1  | 64 bytes from 10.50.3.2: seq=0 ttl=42 time=0.111 ms
container1-1  | 64 bytes from 10.50.3.2: seq=1 ttl=42 time=0.313 ms
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
[+] Stopping 2/2
 ✔ Container repro-container1-1  Stopped                                                                                                                                                                 0.2s 
 ✔ Container repro-container2-1  Stopped                                                                                                                                                                 0.2s 
canceled


$ docker-compose up
Recreating repro-container2-1 ... done
Recreating repro-container1-1 ... done
Attaching to repro_container2_1, repro_container1_1
container1_1  | ----- Starting hook: ./bootstrap.sh
container2_1  | ----- Starting hook: ./bootstrap.sh
container1_1  | ### Bootstrap
container2_1  | ### Bootstrap
container1_1  | ### Using the default container user and group
container2_1  | ### Using the default container user and group
container2_1  | ### Container user and group
container2_1  | ###     user : ping (id: 9031)
container2_1  | ###     group: root (id: 0)
container1_1  | ### Container user and group
container1_1  | ###     user : ping (id: 9031)
container1_1  | ###     group: root (id: 0)
container2_1  | ----- Starting hook: /opt/entrypoint.sh
container1_1  | ----- Starting hook: /opt/entrypoint.sh
container2_1  | Running command: sleep infinity
container1_1  | Running command: ping db
container1_1  | ping: bad address 'db'


$ docker info |grep -A 1 compose
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.24.2


$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown
```

Comment: Thanks, this had completely passed me by.